# How to detect whether spinner item selected or not?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Normally spinner can get item by setOnItemSelected but what if the user didn't click to select at all? Then how should I edit the code for detect whether the user click on the spinner to select item or not? Can anyone please advice me?

Here's my code:

```
s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Rg);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            gender = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Please select your gender", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can check `i` in `onItemSelected` where i is the selected position or you can also call `s.getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> Spinner.getSelectedItem()

or

> Spinner.getSelectedItemId()  //return the id of the selected item (should override the method"getItemId" in the adapter class )

or

> Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() //return the position of the selected item (index in the adapter)

Comment: I found out array set one empty item also can be detect by the TextUtils.isEmpty().